# ¿Cómo forzar el texto solo en 2 líneas usando CSS?

Tags: html, css

Tengo esta tabla rellena con imágenes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero pasarlo a texto, pero no consigo juntar los textos en vertical en 2 líneas.

```css
table {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    table-layout: fixed;
    height: 128px;
    width: 400px;
}

.vertAlign {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    transform: rotate(180deg); 
}


.textStyle{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    font-size: 11pt;
}

div{
    vertical-align:text-bottom;        
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute; 
}

.textAlign{
    width: 213.6px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    text-align:center;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
    font-size: 18pt;
}

.one {
    width: 49.6px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="headers.css">
    </head>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="textAlign">&nbsp;Question</th>
            <th> <div><span class="vertAlign textStyle one">Answers Are Trending</span></div></th>
            <th> <div><span class="vertAlign textStyle two">Average Grade This Store</span></div></th>
            <th> <div><span class="vertAlign textStyle two">Average Grade This District</span></div></th>
            <th> <div><span class="vertAlign textStyle two">Average Grade Company-wide</span></div></th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</html>
```

Esto es lo que he conseguido por ahora, pero no consigo juntarlos en 2 líneas ni que aparezcan los puntos suspensivos si no cabe el texto.

El tamaño total de la tabla es 400 x 180. El primer elemento es 213.6 x 128. El segundo 49.6 x 128 y los otros tres 45.6 x 128.

Comment: Creo que acabo de leerte en forocoches jajaja. Ánimo shur, no es difícil. Dale un par de vueltas. Te doy una pista: Igual te interesa darle una altura concreta al texto,

Comment: Jeje de ahí vengo, buena esa de la altura, va cogiendo forma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hace tiempo use algo similar,

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<!--[if IE]>
   <style>
      .rotate_text
      {
         writing-mode: tb-rl;
         filter: flipH() flipV();
      }
   </style>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
   <style>
      .rotate_text
      {
         -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg); 
         -moz-transform-origin: top left;
         -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
         -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
         -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
         -o-transform-origin:  top left;
          position:relative;
         top:20px;
      }
   </style>
<!--<![endif]-->

   <style>  
      table
      {
         border: 0px  ;
         table-layout: fixed;
         width: 69px; 
      }
      th
      {
          border: 1px solid black;
          width: 50px;
          color:white;
          background-color:black;
      }
      td
       {
          border: 1px solid black;
          width: 50px;
    
      }
      .rotated_cell
      {
         height:300px;
         vertical-align:bottom
      }
   </style>

</head>
<body>

   <table border='1'>
      <tr>
        <th> Primer </th>
         <th class='rotated_cell' width="50px">
            <div class='rotate_text'>Renglon Dos</div>
                   
         </th>
         <th class='rotated_cell'>
            <div class='rotate_text'>Tres</div>
         </th>
   
      </tr>
      <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
      <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
      <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
      <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr>
   </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Solo adapta algunos cambios y listo